# Discord js bot message

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord

I am trying to write a javascript code for discord bot. So when I add message content as '+epic' , the bot needs to send message with epic nick names but in  ONE COLUMN and not in one or two rows like now. Can someone suggest the correct implementation for this?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const auth = require('./auth.json');

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '+epic') {
    msg.reply('lista epic nikova klana je: name - nick1, name - nick2, name - nick3, name - nick4, name - nick5, ...');
  }
});

client.login(auth.token);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend attempting to google the answer to your question for at least 30 minutes prior to posting on a website such as this, as such queries will usually return useful information.

Either way, to create a line-break, you can use `\n`

Integrating this into usable code, you can do, for example:

```js
message.channel.send('Line one \n Line two \n Line three')
```

If this isn't an answer to your question, I recommend trying to rephrase it so that it is more comprehensible.

Comment: Timesis thany you very much , i need  \n